# multiply columns in the list using core python, without any import libraries

Tags: python

If I have the data like this

```
[['6', '0.24','B','C'], ['6', '0.22','A','C'], ['4', '0.20', 'A','X']]
```

and now I want to find out max of `(6/.24, 6/0.22, 4/0.20)`
AND finally, which ever has max value, show col values at index 2 and 3.
Output I am expecting should look something like this:
`27.27273, A, C` (A, C are the corresponding values in the list where we found max value)
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the list by the difference between first 2 elements

```
lst = [['6', '0.24','B','C'], ['6', '0.22','A','C'], ['4', '0.20', 'A','X']]
sorted_lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: float(x[0])/float(x[1]), reverse=True)
x = sorted_lst[0]
result = [float(x[0])/float(x[1]), x[2], x[3]]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[27.272727272727273, 'A', 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

Build a list of the `(6/.24, 6/0.22, 4/0.20)` values and then take the max.

```
a = [['6', '0.24','B','C'], ['6', '0.22','A','C'], ['4', '0.20', 'A','X']]

b = max([float(x[0])/float(x[1]) for x in a])
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_maxrow(data):
  x = [[float(i[0])/float(i[1]), *i[2:]] for i in data]
  return max(x)

x = [['6', '0.24','B','C'], ['6', '0.22','A','C'], ['4', '0.20', 'A','X']]

y = get_maxrow(x)
print(y) # [27.272727272727273, 'A', 'C']
```

Comment: Thanks Anindya that worked. One more follow up question, if I want to make another col and find median on that new column, what could be my best option. IN other words, let us consider one col is price and other one is weight. I want a new col for all lists in my listoflist where new col is product of these two columns. and then i want to find the median of that column.